# NetSuite How do I alter 2FA role settings

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have been having a problem with SDF on a specific instance that won't allow me to request the keys for authentication. I have installed the SDF Developer Role and checked that all necessary permissions are in place. When I make the request for keys, it responds with "Two Factor Authentication is Required" even though on the role I have the "Not Required" setting for this. I checked and in the "Two Factor Authentication Roles" app that SDF Developer is marked as required for integrations. So I looked at other instances where SDF Developer works fine and found out that on this same app it shows as NOT Required for integrations. As depicted in these two images you can see in one that "Mandatory 2FA for Integrations" is checked and the other it is not. The one where it is not checked functions as it should. Does someone know how I can alter this setting? I think this is the culprit or any other suggestion would be great. Thanks for any help with this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting 2018.2, adding some High level permissions to ANY role will automatically activate the 2FA as required and you won't be able to remove it. For your case, you need to compare the permissions on the SDF role were it is working with the permissions of the one where it is not working : then remove the extra permissions and you will be able to inactivate the 2FA.